# Post request with form data as file (wsdl.xml)

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

I am trying to make program which sends post request with form-data file attached and same being uploaded as part of post request.

I have tried lot of ways, but getting page not found.
Here am trying to create multipart body with multipart entity and passing the object to http.

```
public void uploadwsdl() throws Exception {


    MultipartEntityBuilder mb = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
    File file = new File("filpath");
    mb.addBinaryBody("filename", file);
    org.apache.http.HttpEntity fileEntity = mb.build();

    String wsdlUrl = "url";
    URL serverUrl = new URL(
            wsdlUrl);

       String CompanyCodeXML = getData("CompanyCodeMS");

       System.out.println("=====Start XML Payload=====");             

       RestResponse response = retrieveStatusFromAPI(wsdlUrl,fileEntity);
       Assert.assertEquals(response.getCode(), BaseHelper.HTTP_200, "Response Code is not same as Expected:");

       String responseContent = response.getContent();           

       Assert.assertEquals(verifySuccessResponse(responseContent), true, "Response Message does not have JobId");

       Assert.assertNotNull(response, "Response is null");

       System.out.println("=====End XML Payload=====");

}


private RestResponse retrieveStatusFromAPI (String endPointURL,HttpEntity inputEntity)
                 {

                 RestResponse response = null;

                 try {
                 String userCredentials = "test" + ":" + "pwd";
                 String basicAuth = "Basic "+ new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(userCredentials.getBytes()));

                 HttpRequests connection = new HttpRequests();

                 response = connection.httpPost(endPointURL, basicAuth, inputEntity);

                 } catch (Exception ioe) {
                 ioe.printStackTrace();

                 }                    

                 return response;
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

I could find a solution to send post request with file as form-data. Just need to modify the EntityBuilder code as below:

```
final MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
    builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
    builder.addBinaryBody("filename", file, ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY, "some.xml");
    final HttpEntity multiPartEntity = builder.build();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue.I fixed that by changing  'mb.addPart("filename", file)' to 'mb.addBinaryBody("filename", file, ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY, "some.xml");'.

Working solution below : -

```
 public  static void post() throws IOException {
        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        File fileToUse = new File("/Users/username/Documents/abc.xml"); //e.g. /temp/dinnerplate-special.jpg
        MultipartEntityBuilder entitybuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        entitybuilder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        entitybuilder.addBinaryBody("file", fileToUse,ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY, "abc.xml");
        HttpEntity mutiPartHttpEntity = entitybuilder.build();
        RequestBuilder reqbuilder = RequestBuilder.post("postUrl");
        reqbuilder.setEntity(mutiPartHttpEntity);
        reqbuilder.addHeader("Authorization","Basic <token>");
        HttpUriRequest multipartRequest = reqbuilder.build();
        HttpResponse httpresponse = httpclient.execute(multipartRequest);
        System.out.println(httpresponse);
    }
```